# Python Tensorflow under Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to get Tensorflow GPU support going in Python under Windows 10.

What does work;

Download and install Python v3.7.3

```
pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade scipy
```

Run Python from a command prompt and then type import tensorflow
Works and returns no errors
I can run tensorflow Python programs on the CPU (https://github.com/cysmith/neural-style-tf if it matters)

What doesn't work;

I now uninstall CPU tensorflow and install GPU tensorflow

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow
pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

Both uninstall and install finish without errors.

I download and install Cuda Toolkit 9.0 and patches.

I download and extract cuDNN and copy the relevant DLLs to the folders under C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0

C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\extras\demo_suite\oceanFFT.exe runs as expected, so I am now assuming Cuda is installed correctly

Run Python from a command prompt window

Type import tensorflow

fails with these errors...

```
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>>>
```

The path corrctly has the Cuda entries at the start, ie

```
PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\libnvvp;
```

I tried uninstalling Cuda v9 and tried v8 and newest v10.  Same errors.

Any ideas what I need to do to get tensorflow GPU working under Python in Windows 10?

Also tried older Python v3.6.8 after seeing some posts saying v3.7 not supported.

Same errors

```
Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>>>
```

I also went back to Python v3.5.2, installed tensorflow-gpu and got the same errors...

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>>>
```

So before I go mad from trying every combo of Python, Cuda and cuDNN hoping to get a working match, is there any actual steps of which version(s) to install and what sequence to make this work?

Edit: The versions I needed/used to make this work were;

Installed Python v3.6.4

pip3 install --no-cache-dir --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0

pip3 install --no-cache-dir --ignore-installed --upgrade scipy

pip3 install --no-cache-dir --ignore-installed --upgrade opencv_python-3.4.5-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Cuda 9.0

cuDNN needs to be "Download cuDNN v7.2.1 (August 7, 2018), for CUDA 9.2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Tensorflow install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu)

> **Windows setup**
>
> See the hardware requirements and software requirements listed above.
>   Read the CUDA® install guide for Windows.
>
> Make sure the installed NVIDIA software packages match the versions
>   listed above. In particular, TensorFlow will not load without the
>   cuDNN64_7.dll file. To use a different version, see the Windows build
>   from source guide.

Maybe you don't have the specified file cuDNN64_7.dll

Please check if the file is present in C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin 
Where 9.0 is the version of CUDA

Actually I have this setup working in Windows 10

- Python 3.6.4
- Tensorflow 1.12.0
- CUDA 9.0

**Edit**: Some research I found this related links to the issue

Search for DLL: [Tensorflow install errors](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors)

Issues related:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22512

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22794

Comment: Using your versions helped.  Many thanks.  See original question for working versions I used.

Answer (score 0):

For all those with the „DLL load failed“ problem under Windows 10/Python 3.6.x/RTX20xx.

The combination of CUDA 10.0 (not 10.1!), cuDNN 7.5.0 works fine for me (as of 12 April 2019). I also have Visual Studio 2015 installed (but not sure if needed).

Don‘t forget to add the location of the cuDNN *.dll file (it‘s the `/bin/` dir in your CUDA dir) to your PATH.

If you have CUDA 10.1, just uninstall it, install 10.0, add the cuDNN files to the 10.0 dir, and reboot.

Tensorflow can be installed using `pip install tensorflow-gpu`